# accumulate the element ahead of nth element in list

Tags: scala

I want to create a list from the n+1th value till n.length , where n is the value passed to a function

```
    def test(n:String) ={
  val list = List("1","12","30","40","50")
  list match{
    case s::rest if s==n => Seq(rest).flatten
    case _ => Nil
  }
}
```

if "`12"` is passed , I get a empty list.

Expected Output = `List("30,40,50")`

Comment: What is the input for your expected output? 2? Or 3? What is `n.length`? Did you mean `list.length`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting it another way, you want to remove the first `n` values from the list. For this, you use `drop`:

```
list.drop(n)
```

If you want to drop values based on a condition, use `dropWhile`:

```
list.dropWhile(_ != "30")
```

To exclude the matching element, use another `drop`:

```
list.dropWhile(_ != "12").drop(1)
```

[ As noted in the comments, using `tail` could cause exception if the element is not found ]

Comment: If `"12"` is the last element, your last expression will throw. I guess you meant `list.dropWhile(_ != "12").tailOpt.getOrElse(Nil)`

Comment: if last element it returns List()

Comment: He wants to remove elements, before and including the element ie., string he passes, but he is not passing the number of values to be removed. `drop` function takes an `Int` parameter, But he is passing a particular string value `after which he wants to retain all elements and remove all those before including the element` passed.`list. dropWhile(_ != "12").tail` only will do.

Comment: Yes.. tail could cause exception.Now it should be ok after adding drop(1).